# Javascript - webpack error on importing module

Tags: javascript, module, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a folder `assets/js` with my scripts. I have made 2 scripts like it is shown in the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) in that folder. One handles the ajax request, and the other imports it. So this is the file `ajax.js`:

```
function getJSON(url, callback) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    callback(this.responseText)
  };
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.send();
}

export function getUsefulContents(url, callback) {
  getJSON(url, data => callback(JSON.parse(data)));
}
```

And this is the `app.js`

```
import { getUsefulContents } from 'ajax';

var url = 'someUrl.com';

getUsefulContents(url, data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I have installed babel-core, babel-loader and babel-preset-es2015. The webpack.config.js is setup like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './assets/js/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: './dist/app.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, I get:

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ajax' in '/Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/assets/js'
 @ ./assets/js/app.js 3:12-27
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./assets/js/app.js
```

This is the detailed error that I get on running the `webpack --display-error-details` command:

```
ERROR in ./assets/js/app.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'ajax' in '/Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/assets/js'
resolve 'ajax' in '/Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/assets/js'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/package.json (relative path: ./assets/js)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
  after using description file: /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/package.json (relative path: ./assets/js)
    resolve as module
      /Users/myUser/Projects/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/myUser/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/assets/js/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/assets/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/node_modules
        using description file: /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        after using description file: /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          using description file: /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/ajax)
            as directory
              /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/node_modules/ajax doesn't exist
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/node_modules/ajax doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/node_modules/ajax.js doesn't exist
            .json
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /Users/myUser/Projects/Pagination/node_modules/ajax.json doesn't exist
```

When I have changed the import line to this:

```
import { getUsefulContents } from './ajax';
```

I got:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That error looks like you have the `import` statement loaded in the browser. Are you by chance including the original source in your HTML?

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to change the path when I started using webpack, thank you very much!